# How to set in my own module dependency on a composer package?

Tags: 7, composer

I have some of my own modules written on Drupal 7 that use composer packages. These composer packages are downloaded with the module Composer Manager.

How can I set explicitly the dependency on a composer package on my own module?

Should I describe it somehow on my module's .info-file or should I do it via a hook?

It's because if I don't do it, the Composer Manager can remove these packages from the site on the next updating. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any example.

Comment: Surely you put them in your module’s composer.json?

Comment: No, I didn't. Could you share an example for a custom module?

Comment: That wasn't meant to sound rude by the way, I meant "Surely _one_ would put them in composer.json" :) I don't have an example, and it's been a long time since I user D7, but I thought the point of Composer Manager was that it recurses through module folders looking for composer.json files, and merging them into one to be installed. You can probably take a contrib module's file as an example, I guess the main point would be to make sure the `require` section is sensible and has your dependencies in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add dependencies in your module.

Navigate to your module's root folder. Run `composer init`. When you get to the question `Would you like to define your dependencies (require) interactively`, say yes. You can then declare any composer libraries your module depends on.

You can also manually create a `composer.json` file that looks something like this:

```
{
    "name": "uniquenamespace/packagename",
    "description": "This module does some stuff",
    "type": "drupal-module",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Some Guy",
            "homepage": "https://www.example.com/some_guy",
            "role": "Maintainer"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "somevendor/somepackage": "^1.9"
    },
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later"
}
```

Run `composer validate` to check that your `composer.json` file is valid.

Comment: Thank you. A question. How should I name the module? I mean the "name" property.
And is there another way? For example, a hook to define the dependency.

Comment: I use `jaypan/packagename`. The first part needs to be unique in the internet, so use something no one else will use. `packagename` should be your Drupal module machine name.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you.